# Custom navigable combo box control

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to build a custom combobox with forward and back buttons I am starting out and I am having trouble with being able to populate the combobox with generic lists.

so far I have this:

public partial class NavigableComboBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
#region Constructor

public NavigableComboBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

#endregion

#region Dependency Properties

#region ListSource

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public ObservableCollection<object> ListSource
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ListSourceProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(NavigableComboBox.ListSourceProperty, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ListSource");
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2211:NonConstantFieldsShouldNotBeVisible")]
public static DependencyProperty ListSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     "ListSource",
     typeof(ObservableCollection<object>),
     typeof(NavigableComboBox),
     new PropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));

#endregion

#region ListSource

public object SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(NavigableComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}

public static DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedItem",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(NavigableComboBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));

#endregion

#endregion

private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((NavigableComboBox)d).ListSource = (ObservableCollection<object>)e.NewValue;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

and this for xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Divestco.WinPics.Components.Common.UserControls.NavigableComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Divestco.WinPics.Components.Common.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="55" d:DesignWidth="200">
        <Grid>
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I am using it as so on the main form:

```
<UserControls:NavigableComboBox ListSource="{Binding Path=MapModel.GridsInProject}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedGrid}"/>
```

I place break points on the dependency property but they are never hit. When using a regular combobox and not my custom control it is filled with out a problem so I know the main form bindings are correct. I also am not getting any error messages when running

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? or even better does anyone know of a pre made control like this?

**The control I envision will have a combobox and a next previous button on either side. The user can select an item from the dropdown list or scroll through by pressing next or previous. The control should be able to take any custom collection of objects and allow you to choose the display field. For example I have a collection of grid objects and a collection of horizon objects and I will populate the control with one of them depending on other factors in the app. Both collections have a string property named "Name" that will be the display field.**

[image]

Comment: Your breakpoints will not be hit because the setters and getters are not called by the Binding System. BTW what do you mean by a navigable combobox? I think that should probably be a `UserControl` or something. Can you Post a screenshot of what you need?

Comment: And you don't put collection properties in a `Selector` which already has an `ItemsSource` collection property.

Comment: I updated the question with an image I drew of what I was looking to make in the end.

Comment: Your problem here is the DP `ListSource` is not in the DataContext of the `ComboBox` for it to bind to. You can either in the constructor of `NavigableComboBox` set `DataContext = this;` or use a `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding on the `ComboBox` to let it get to `ListSource`. However it does look like your over-complicating this issue, just have the DP's in `NavigableComboBox` as pass-through properties to bind to the ComboBox and let the combo-box deal with it. Your two buttons on their Command execute can just increase/decrease selected index by one and you're done.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example? I still cannot get it to work. What do I do when there are 2 different types of custom objects that could populate the list depending on other variables, and everyone of those objects have a Name property that is the display property? Example: list could be collection of grids, or a collection of horizons. Both have a property Name: that is for display value. I can cast to that I need when selected value object is returned.